# Argrelmin does not return a value

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

Why is min_idxs empty, please? This code works with my original data and this problem happens when I change the curve, but after using artificial data, the same error occurred. Many thanks

```
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import argrelmin

data = [[1,2,3,4,5], [0, 1, 0, 2, 0.1], [0.05, 0.06, 0.03, 0.03, 0.01]]

# distane between a point and the curve
def distance(x, y, x0, y0):
    d_x = x - x0
    d_y = y - y0
    dis = np.sqrt( d_x**2 + d_y**2 )
    return dis

z_1v1 = np.polyfit(data[0], data[1], 2)
f_1v1 = np.poly1d(z_1v1)
# Creating more points on the streamline - defining new time with more steps
x_new = list(np.arange(1,5,0.1))
y_new = f_1v1(x_new)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[12,8])

ax.errorbar(data[0], data[1], yerr=data[2], fmt='o')

plt.xlim(1,5)
ax.plot(x_new, y_new)

plt.show()

min_dis = []

for i in range(len(data[0])-1):
    dis = distance(np.array(x_new), np.array(y_new), data[0][i], data[1][i])
    # find the minima
    print(dis)
    min_idxs = argrelmin(np.array(dis))[0]   # <-----------------
    # take the minimum
    print(min_idxs)
    glob_min_idx = min_idxs[np.argmin(dis[min_idxs])]
    # coordinates and distance
    min_x = x_new[glob_min_idx]
    min_y = y_new[glob_min_idx]
    min_d = dis[glob_min_idx]
    min_dis.append(min_d)
```

**Edit after advice**
I tried another function and I obtained the error: min_x2 = x_data[glob_min_idx2]
IndexError: list index out of range
What is wrong with this, please? Why is glob_min_idx2 so large?

```
import numpy as np  
from scipy.signal import argrelmin

# distance between a point and the curve
def distance(x, y, x0, y0):
    d_x = x - x0
    d_y = y - y0
    dis = np.sqrt( d_x**2 + d_y**2 )
    return dis

x = np.arange(40000,53000,0.05)
a = 0.212559
b = 0.000609114
c = 4.2143e-06
y = a*np.sin(b*x) + c*x


min_dis2 = []

x_data = [50124.7613, 50131.5144, 50142.5124, 50146.7476, 50157.5567, 50190.5148, 50194.5244, 50452.5951, 50460.7548, 50467.67, 50471.7473, 50515.6811, 50526.2968, 50533.4945, 50540.4819, 50544.4719, 50551.4765, 51183.8158, 51190.7394, 51197.511, 51555.594, 51570.8073, 52278.7665, 16481.7836, 17577.7837, 17905.9414, 18996.8521, 40607.7343, 42075.791, 42724.911, 42886.626, 43092.8355, 43502.5255, 43505.6196, 43885.5637, 43892.5748, 44955.6822, 45246.86, 45354.813]
y_data = [0.1466, 0.04017, 0.06292, 0.18241, 0.01626, 0.04861, -0.0575, 0.09487, 0.02313, 0.0788, 0.04038, 0.07319, -0.28636, 0.05181, 0.17968, 0.05397, 0.19904, 0.08967, 0.15374, 0.06581, 0.08134, 0.20368, 0.25938, 0.41974, 0.26695, 0.53911, -0.58736, 0.03152, 0.1488, 0.35727, 0.18736, 0.61096, 0.10106, 0.45135, 0.37749, 0.52906, 0.40931, -0.62887, 0.31546]


for i in range(len(x_data)-1):
    dis2 = distance(np.array(x), np.array(y), x_data[i], y_data[i])
    # find the minima
    min_idxs2 = argrelmin(np.array(dis2))[0]
    # take the minimum
    if not min_idxs2.size:
        min_idxs2 = [np.argmin(dis2)]
    print(min_idxs2)
    glob_min_idx2 = min_idxs2[np.argmin(dis2[min_idxs2])]
    print(glob_min_idx2)
    # coordinates and distance
    print(len(x_data))
    min_x2 = x_data[glob_min_idx2]
    min_y2 = y_data[glob_min_idx2]
    min_d2 = dis2[glob_min_idx2]
    min_dis2.append(min_d2)


print(min_dis2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argrelextrema`, `argrelmax`, `argrelmin` can find local/global maxima and minima but not if they are the extremes of interval (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelmin.html).

In your case, the first `dis` is monotonically increasing, so the local minimum is the global minimum (in the defined interval) and it's the left extreme.

You can simply add an `if` statement

```
for i in range(len(data[0])-1):
    dis = distance(np.array(x_new), np.array(y_new), data[0][i], data[1][i])
    # find the minima
    min_idxs = argrelmin(dis)[0]
    # =========================================
    # if no minima take left or right extreme
    # =========================================
    if not min_idxs.size:
        min_idxs = [np.argmin(dis)]
    glob_min_idx = min_idxs[np.argmin(dis[min_idxs])]
    plt.plot(dis)
    plt.plot(glob_min_idx, dis[glob_min_idx], 'o')
    plt.title(f'dis {i}')
    plt.show()
    # coordinates and distance
    min_x = x_new[glob_min_idx]
    min_y = y_new[glob_min_idx]
    min_d = dis[glob_min_idx]
    min_dis.append(min_d)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. One, more question, please. I tried another function and do not understand why glob_min_idx is so large. I added the code to my question.

Comment: That's because you're taking `min_x2 = x_data[glob_min_idx2]` instead of `min_x2 = x[glob_min_idx2]`. `x_data` contains only 39 elements, `x` 260000

Comment: YVW. Please, if you think that the answer solved your issue, accept it, thanks.